# Join two lists in order

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Suppose I have :

```
odd = [1,3,5,7,9]
even = [2,4,6,8,10]
```

and I want a list where the output would be :

```
temp = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

What should be the approach in python to get this output : "temp" with help of odd and even lists

Please also consider that lists might not be of same length.
These are two actual lists:

```
low = ['Low: 53 °F', 'Low: 52 °F', 'Low: 53 °F', 'Low: 54 °F', 'Low: 52 °F']
high = ['High: 65 °F', 'High: 64 °F', 'High: 66 °F', 'High: 66 °F']
```

I want to display as:

```
temp =['Low: 53 °F',
 'High: 65 °F',
 'Low: 52 °F',
 'High: 64 °F',
 'Low: 53 °F',
 'High: 66 °F',
 'Low: 54 °F',
 'High: 66 °F',                                                                                                                         
 'Low': 52 °F' ]
```

Comment: please also consider that lists might not be of same length

Comment: low = ['Low: 53 °F', 'Low: 52 °F', 'Low: 53 °F', 'Low: 54 °F', 'Low: 52 °F'].                               high = ['High: 65 °F', 'High: 64 °F', 'High: 66 °F', 'High: 66 °F'].  these are two actual lists  want to display as temp =['Low: 53 °F',
 'High: 65 °F',
 'Low: 52 °F',
 'High: 64 °F',
 'Low: 53 °F',
 'High: 66 °F',
 'Low: 54 °F',
 'High: 66 °F',                                                                                                                         
 'Low': 52 °F' ]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip` and chain them (works for lists of different length also):

```
from itertools import chain

odd = [1,3,5,7,9,1]
even = [2,4,6,8,10,4,5,6,7]

zipped = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(odd, even)))
od = len(odd)
ev = len(even)
if od == ev:
    print(zipped)
elif od > ev:
    print(zipped + odd[ev-od:])
else:
    print(zipped + even[od-ev:])
```

Comment: what if odd has 5 element and even has only 4

Comment: @AbhishekMishra, Please explain how do you want it to look like then?

Comment: low = ['Low: 53 °F', 'Low: 52 °F', 'Low: 53 °F', 'Low: 54 °F', 'Low: 52 °F']. high = ['High: 65 °F', 'High: 64 °F', 'High: 66 °F', 'High: 66 °F']. these are two actual lists want to display as temp =['Low: 53 °F', 'High: 65 °F', 'Low: 52 °F', 'High: 64 °F', 'Low: 53 °F', 'High: 66 °F', 'Low: 54 °F', 'High: 66 °F', 'Low': 52 °F' ]

Answer (score 2):

You can interleave them with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a nested [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
temp = [x for pair in zip(odd, even) for x in pair]
```

There is also a util -- [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) -- to achieve the flattening:

```
from itertools import chain

temp = [*chain(*zip(odd, even))]
```

Comment: Nice solution, except that it drops the extra elements from the longer list if they're not the same length.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're looking to put all items in sorted order**, I would advise to look toward this one-liner:

```
odd = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
even = [2,4,6,8,10]

temp = sorted([*odd, *even])
# temp = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

What it does is that it unpacks both lists into the new list and sorts it.

Note, with this approach, you can do with more than one initial list:

```
odd = [1,3,5,7]
even = [2,4,6,8]
mixed = [23, 111, 71]

temp = sorted([*odd, *even, *mixed])
# temp = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,23,71,111]
```

Otherwise, I would suggest you to use the following (*verbose and clear in what it does*) function.

```
def func(od, ev):
    ret = []
    for a, b in zip(od,ev):
        ret.append(a)
        ret.append(b)
    return ret
```

Comment: I guess the OP does not mean sorted when they say "in order". More like interleave them in their original order. But could be clearer with a better example.

Comment: @schwobaseggl yeah, I totally messed that part. For this case, good thing there are good approaches mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found works. It uses the function `.sort()` and makes a new list. Here is the code and I hope it all makes sense:

```
odd = [1,3,5,7,9]
even = [2,4,6,8,10]
new = odd + even
```

New list output

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Sort new list

```
new.sort()
```

new sort list output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Instead of using sort function , try to use merge sort which is a sorting algorithm having n(log(n)) time complexity in wort case also. Then your solution will be more efficient.

Comment: @NandiniAshokTuptewar I haven't heard of merge sort before, would you be able to provide a link on it for me? Cheers mate :)

Comment: link for merge sort :  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/

Comment: @NandiniAshokTuptewar Thanks for the link. The code for merge sort is pretty long. How does it make it better than `.sort()`?

Comment: This is not at all what the OP wants, please read the question completely. As the second example makes very clear, he wants to interleave the lists, not get a sorted output, which would have been trivial.

Answer (score 0):

odd = [1,3,5,7,9]

even = [2,4,6,8,10]

temp=odd + even

temp.sort()

print(temp)

Answer (score 0):

```py
    odd = [1,3,5,7,9] 
    even = [2,4,6,8,10]

    temp = odd + even
    temp.sort()
    print(temp)
```